# How can I return a separate value along with the result of a promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I am returning a promise, but I am trying to return a string AND a promise. Is there a way to link the two **without** having to return it from the promise?

for example if my input was

```
[
  {
    keepme:"abcd",
    sql:"select top(1) * from X"
  }
]
```

My goal is to return

```
[
  {
    keepme:"abcd",
    sql:"select top(1) * from X",
    resultOfPromise:[{columnA:1,columnB:2}]
  }
]
```

Here is my code so far. It returns the promise, but not the `abcd` value:

```
let qq=[{keepme:"abcd",sql:"select top(1) * from X"}]

async function myFunc(sql:string){
    return [{columnA:1,columnB:2}]
}

async function run(){
let prom=qq.map((qq) => myFunc(qq.sql));

    for (let p of await (Promise as any).allSettled(prom)) {
      console.log(p.value)
    }
}

run();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return an object with the promise result as one of its properties:

```js
const getDataWithInputs = async (keepme, ...input) => {
  let data = await getData(...input);
  return {
    data,
    input,
    keepme
  }
}
```

and when calling it:

```js
let prom = qq.map((qq) => myFunc(qq.keepme, qq.sql));
```

Also you should always pad operators with spaces.

Comment: Im afraid this won't work because my question stated I was unable to modify the promise function `myFunc()`. It belongs to someone elses code.  I apologize if that wasn't clear

Comment: You can add a wrapper. In my example, `myFunc` would be `getData`

Comment: hmm this seems like it would work, but I think your example might not match my code... I think you would change myFunc to getDateWithInputs and getData to myFunc right?

Answer (score 1):

You could make your `map` callback `async` and inject the promised value with `await` into a new object literal, which copies the other properties from `qq`:

```js
let qq = [{keepme: "abcd", sql: "select top(1) * from X"}];

async function myFunc(sql) {
    return [{columnA: 1, columnB: 2}];
}

async function run(){
    let prom = qq.map(async (qq) => ({
        ...qq,
        resultOfPromise: await myFunc(qq.sql)
    }));

    for (let p of await Promise.allSettled(prom)) {
        console.log(p.value);
    }
}

run();
```